# Debugfs file mode flags?

Tags: linux-kernel

What flags do I use for debugfs_create_file_N(...)?  All the resources I can find basically say 'set them as appropriate'.

I've tried 777, MAY_WRITE|MAY_READ, and FMODE_WRITE|FMODE_READ; but so far cat'ing the file only gives me a '0'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't you hear, "777 is almost always wrong" :-)  `MAY_*` and `FMODE_*` are not file modes either, but internal flags and file states.

Better:

```
debugfs_create_file(..., S_ISREG | S_IRUGO | S_IWUSR, ...);
```

Comment: Yeah, we were mostly groping in the dark due to the lack of documentation.  Where can I find documentation on how S_* are interpreted?

Comment: Uh, S_* are the standard mode_t modes - and are best served as mnemonic constants rather than octal values. See stat(2).

Answer (score 2):

For a world readable file, use `S_IRUGO`

```
validation@tb04:~> ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/spc0/registers
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 14  2011 /sys/kernel/debug/spc0/registers
```

Internally, this sets `S_IRUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH` which set read mode for the user, group, and others. See `include/stat.h` in the kernel for other macro definitions.